# Manipulating the path to an image so it can be opened from a users directory rather than my own

Tags: image, python-3.x, path, filepath

I am writing a program to place text onto a specific image. I intend for the program to be used by multiple users so there would be a different directory to the required image each time.

How do I manipulate the path to the image so this is possible? I did intend to attach the "blank" image to the user as well as the script but I wonder if it's possible to embed the image within the script so I only send one file.

This is my first Python program so apologies if the solution is alarmingly obvious.

```
    im=Image.open(r"C:\Users\Desktop\image") #Opens image 
    font_type = ImageFont.truetype(r"C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf", 59)
    txt=Image.new('L', (4677,3307))
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)
    d.text( (3700, 3060), OD,  font=font_type, fill= 255)
    w=txt.rotate(90,  expand=1) #Rotates the OD annotation 90 degrees
    im.paste( ImageOps.colorize(w, (34,0,0), (255,100,84)), (242,60),  w)
```

The path will be different every time so it must be able to identify the image wherever it is saved on a users computer.

Comment: Please clarify the question including a [minimal, complete and verfiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. If necessary you should be able to attach the image to the question too.

Answer (score 0):

[Working with Directories](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filesys.html): This is the module you're gonna want to use to get a more dynamic filepathing so others can use your code.

I believe os.path is what you're going to want to use?

Sorry, I only have cursory knowledge of the module, so I'm not able to give a fantastic description of how to use it